# Valgrind errors not reported when function is inlined

Tags: c++, valgrind

I've been trying to track down the cause of an error reported by Valgrind (see below). It says that a 'Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)', pointing to a function call. When I inline that function however, the error is no longer reported.

### Original function

```
bool is_unsafe_piece_hook(Gamestate & gs, const Square s) {

    Piece p = gs.board.get(s);
    Colour c = colour(p);
    if (p == EMPTY) { return true; }

    SquareControlStatus ss = gs.control_cache->get_control_status(s);

    if (is_weak_status(gs, s, c, ss)) {
        return gs.add_frame(unsafe_piece_hook.id, FeatureFrame{s, SQUARE_SENTINEL, ss.min_w, ss.min_b});
    }

*   if (pawn_is_en_passantable(gs, s)) {
        return gs.add_frame(unsafe_piece_hook.id, FeatureFrame{s, SQUARE_SENTINEL, ss.min_w, ss.min_b});
    }

    return true;
}
```

### Error reported

The line referred to is marked with an asterisk above.

```
==22305== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22305==    at 0x196D56: is_unsafe_piece_hook(Gamestate&, Square) (unsafe_piece.cpp:38)
==22305==    by 0x194963: discover_feature_frames (cands.cpp:22)
==22305==    by 0x194963: cands(Gamestate&, CandSet*) (cands.cpp:65)
==22305==    by 0x192910: deepen(SearchNode*, CandList, int, Observer&, bool) (greedy.cpp:117)
==22305==    by 0x192AD0: deepen(SearchNode*, CandList, int, Observer&, bool) (greedy.cpp:77)
==22305==    by 0x192A01: deepen(SearchNode*, CandList, int, Observer&, bool) (greedy.cpp:133)
==22305==    by 0x192A01: deepen(SearchNode*, CandList, int, Observer&, bool) (greedy.cpp:133)
==22305==    by 0x192F8B: visit_node(SearchNode*, Observer&) [clone .part.0] (greedy.cpp:181)
==22305==    by 0x193135: visit_node (greedy.cpp:151)
==22305==    by 0x193135: visit_best_line(SearchNode*, bool, Observer&) (greedy.cpp:272)
==22305==    by 0x193117: visit_best_line(SearchNode*, bool, Observer&) (greedy.cpp:271)
==22305==    by 0x193117: visit_best_line(SearchNode*, bool, Observer&) (greedy.cpp:271)
==22305==    by 0x193117: visit_best_line(SearchNode*, bool, Observer&) (greedy.cpp:271)
==22305==    by 0x1932B1: visit_best_line (greedy.cpp:271)
==22305==    by 0x1932B1: greedy_search(SearchNode*, int, Observer&) (greedy.cpp:299)
==22305==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==22305==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22305==    by 0x18FC3C: new_node(Gamestate const&, Move) (search.cpp:183)
==22305==    by 0x1928D5: deepen(SearchNode*, CandList, int, Observer&, bool) (greedy.cpp:116)
==22305==    by 0x192AD0: deepen(SearchNode*, CandList, int, Observer&, bool) (greedy.cpp:77)
==22305==    by 0x192A01: deepen(SearchNode*, CandList, int, Observer&, bool) (greedy.cpp:133)
==22305==    by 0x192A01: deepen(SearchNode*, CandList, int, Observer&, bool) (greedy.cpp:133)
==22305==    by 0x192F8B: visit_node(SearchNode*, Observer&) [clone .part.0] (greedy.cpp:181)
==22305==    by 0x193135: visit_node (greedy.cpp:151)
==22305==    by 0x193135: visit_best_line(SearchNode*, bool, Observer&) (greedy.cpp:272)
==22305==    by 0x193117: visit_best_line(SearchNode*, bool, Observer&) (greedy.cpp:271)
==22305==    by 0x193117: visit_best_line(SearchNode*, bool, Observer&) (greedy.cpp:271)
==22305==    by 0x193117: visit_best_line(SearchNode*, bool, Observer&) (greedy.cpp:271)
==22305==    by 0x1932B1: visit_best_line (greedy.cpp:271)
==22305==    by 0x1932B1: greedy_search(SearchNode*, int, Observer&) (greedy.cpp:299)
```

### Modified function

Valgrind reports no errors when using the modified version. The function `pawn_is_en_passantable` has been inlined (manually) corresponding to the code within the inner block marked with asterisks.

```
bool is_unsafe_piece_hook(Gamestate & gs, const Square s) {

    Piece p = gs.board.get(s);
    Colour c = colour(p);
    if (p == EMPTY) { return true; }

    SquareControlStatus ss = gs.control_cache->get_control_status(s);

    if (is_weak_status(gs, s, c, ss)) {
        return gs.add_frame(unsafe_piece_hook.id, FeatureFrame{s, SQUARE_SENTINEL, ss.min_w, ss.min_b});
    }

    bool en_passantable;
*   {
        Piece p2 = gs.board.get(s);
        Colour c2 = colour(p2);

        // check we have a pawn on the correct square
        if (!gs.board.get_ep_exists()
            || type(p2) != PAWN
            || !equal(s, gs.board.get_ep_pawn_square())) {
            return false;
        }

        // check there is indeed a pawn to capture it
        Square l_sq = mksq(s.x + 1, s.y);
        Square r_sq = mksq(s.x - 1, s.y);
        Piece enemy_pawn = (c2 == WHITE ? B_PAWN : W_PAWN);

        en_passantable =
                (s.x > 0 && gs.board.get(l_sq) == enemy_pawn)
               || (s.x < 7 && gs.board.get(r_sq) == enemy_pawn);
*   }

    if (en_passantable) {
        return gs.add_frame(unsafe_piece_hook.id, FeatureFrame{s, SQUARE_SENTINEL, ss.min_w, ss.min_b});
    }

    return true;
}
```

### Question

1. Is there actually an error here?
2. Why does Valgrind behave like this?

I appreciate there might not be enough information to answer (1) - any suggestions on how to continue debugging also appreciated (this is the only error reported; I've check the initialisation the error refers to several times and the project also compiles cleanly with `-Wall -Wextra`).

Edit: using g++ 9.4.0 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Which platform compiler? Note tools introduced to compilers which are great replacement for valgrind: address sanitizer, undefined sanitizer, ... .

Comment: Also note that gcc do not detect some warnings when optimizations are disabled. Use `-Og`.

Comment: Impossible to answer either of these without more information.  My money is that there's a bug though, likely in `Gamestate`.  Inlining the function probably gives the compiler enough information to optimize away some checks, thus valgrind never hits the bug.  Address sanitizer is your best bet here.

Comment: The compiler may have optimized away the error. The only way to be sure is to analyze the assembler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, I used the sanitizer's @MarekR suggested to fix the bug (along with many others). As it happens, it's actually visible in the inlined function (the checks just before the last asterisk are the wrong way round; x>0 <-> x+1 instead of x>0 <-> x-1). Got some new debugging tools which is great!